Unable to remove "Complete this Field" on Cancel button click from lwc input type
In LWC, there are multiple input fields but input types are combo box & text, and a few of them are required.
Below is the html code
<lightning-combobox
    class ='validateClass'
    data-fieldname={fieldDetail.fieldAPIName}
    data-objname={secVal.objectName}
    name="Picklist"
    label={fieldDetail.fieldLabel}
    value={pickListOptionSelection}
    placeholder="Select"
    options={fieldDetail.pickListOptions}
    onchange={handleChangePickList} 
    required = {fieldDetail.isRequired}>
</lightning-combobox>

<lightning-input class ='validateClass' 
                 data-objname={secVal.objectName}
                 data-fieldname={fieldDetail.fieldAPIName}
                 value={inputData}
                type={fieldDetail.fieldType} 
                variant="standard" 
                name={fieldDetail.fieldAPIName} 
                required = {fieldDetail.isRequired}
                label={fieldDetail.fieldLabel} 
                placeholder="type here..." 
                onblur={handleInputBlur}>
</lightning-input>

On clicking on the Cancel button we have to reset the form. Below is the code that is written on cancel button click.
    //method will call on cancel button click
    handleCancelClick(){
        this.isDatatableVisible = false;
        this.template.querySelectorAll('.validateClass').forEach(each => {
                                                                    each.value = '';
                                                                    if(each.required){
                                                                        each.classList?.remove('slds-has-error');
                                                                        each.className?.replace('slds-has-error');
                                                                    }
                                                                });
    }

I've attached a picture of the issue.


I've tried using below code but same issue.
this.template.querySelectorAll('.validateClass').forEach(each => {
                                                                    each.reset();
                                                                });


As per my understanding, this has to be implemented custom including the logic to enforce required attribute. Implement the required logic as custom logic as mentioned in this post : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/250245/display-required-error-message-upon-submitting-a-lwc-form?rq=1 and then remove it using setCustomValidity('')

@Sarang
Thanks for answering. I've tried using setCustomValidity('') but still same issue.

Probably something is missing in your implementation. check out my answer below.

Once we decide to implement custom validation, everything has to be implemented custom including removing the 'required' attribute, the red asterix and messages. I implemented this custom, considering 2 input text fields and 1 combobox. It is working as per your expected behavior.

HTML

<template>
    <div class="custom-input-container">
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
        <lightning-input name='First Input' label='First Input' type="text" class='validateClass'
            message-when-value-missing={completeTheFieldMsg} onblur={validate}>
        </lightning-input>
    </div>

    <div class="custom-input-container">
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
        <lightning-input name='Second Input' label='Second Input' type="text" class='validateClass'
            message-when-value-missing={completeTheFieldMsg} onblur={validate}>
        </lightning-input>
    </div>

    <div class="custom-input-container">
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
        <lightning-combobox class='validateClass' data-element="combo-box" name='Third Input' label='Third Input'
            options={options} onchange={handleChange} message-when-value-missing={completeTheFieldMsg}
            onblur={validate}>
        </lightning-combobox>
    </div>
    <br>
    <lightning-button name="Cancel" label="Cancel" onclick={onCancel}></lightning-button>


JS

import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class PageLayoutDetails extends LightningElement {

value = '';
completeTheFieldMsg = 'Complete this entry.'
get options() {
    return [
        { label: 'Select a Value', value: '' }, { label: 'New', value: 'new' },
        { label: 'In Progress', value: 'inProgress' },
        { label: 'Finished', value: 'finished' },
    ];
}
handleChange(event) {
    this.value = event.detail.value;
}

validate(evt) {
    const inputEle = evt.target;
    if (inputEle.value) {
        inputEle.setCustomValidity('');
    }
    else {
        inputEle.setCustomValidity(this.completeTheFieldMsg);
    }
    inputEle.reportValidity();
}

onCancel(event) {
    this.template.querySelectorAll('.validateClass').forEach(inputElem => {
        inputElem.setCustomValidity('');
        inputElem.reportValidity();
        inputElem.value = '';
    });
}

}

CSS

.custom-input-container {
display: flex;
}
.required-indicator {
color: red;
margin-right: 0.2rem;
font-size: 1.2rem;
}

